# Implement iap2(MFi protocol) on raspberryPi

Tags: ios, raspberry-pi, usb, usb-drive

All

Background:
if we want to access data form apple device,we should use iap protocol to connect between apple device and raspberry Pi.

Question:
when the apple device connect to the Pi via USB, do we have some driver for apple device to use? 
I want to send initialisation data(FF 55 02 00 EE 10) to apple device.

Comment: maybe use libusb library to send data to apple device?

Answer (score 1):

You need an MFi chip on your Raspberry Pi to pass the iAP authentication.